# Symfony2.2 render ESI template

Tags: caching, symfony, esi, symfony-2.2

From [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html#using-esi-in-symfony2), there is no example of how to render a template inside template using ESI. Is it possible to do that?

For example, I have a template `index.html.php` and I want to render `form.html.php` template with ESI. How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the documentation page you provided, you can render one controller within another using:

```
{{ render_esi(controller('YourBundle:Default:news', { 'max': 5 })) }}
```

You can also use a route name instead of the controller reference:

```
{{ render_esi(url('latest_news', { 'max': 5 })) }}
```

However, you will need to set up a [gateway cache](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html#caching-with-a-gateway-cache) for ESI to work.