# Symfony2 - passing values between ESI and main request

Tags: symfony

I need to pass a value from the main controller in a route to the controller used by an ESI.

So a controller renders a Twig template and in Twig this is called:

```
{{ render_esi(url('route_name')) }}
```

The above renders a controller. It's those two controllers I need to pass information between.

I've noticed that using $request->attributes does't work, even though it would if one wasn't an ESI:

```
//these WON'T pass between master request and ESI
$request->attributes->set('the_value');
$request->attributes->get('the_value');
```

Sessions aren't ideal as I would need to ensure they were cleared on some occasions.

I really just want the same request to pass some information once. I was hoping that the $request->attributes would be shared as to me it's one request (although I believe Symfony calls it one master request with various sub-requests and I'm guessing $request->attributes are locked to that scope).

Passing it as a query param in the ESI call isn't good either as it can sometimes be an array of info that needs to be passed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass arguments to your action like this:

```
{{ render_esi(controller('YourBundle:Default:news', { 'max': 5 })) }}
```

or use route parameters like this

```
{{ render_esi(url('latest_news', { 'max': 5 })) }}
```

as correctly answered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269836/symfony2-2-render-esi-template).

Comment: Hi. Thanks, but just 2 thoughts. (1) That would pass it as a query string param in the ESI call (2) How is that available in the controller. In Twig I could use {{ var_name }}, but how in a controller?

Comment: The controller argument and the query string are available as you are used to from using symfony without ESI ... $request->getParameter('yourparameter') ... only difference is the request not being a master request but a sub-request. but that doesn't matter if you only want to receive the query parameters. The sub-request is just the internal one.